# pandas to multiple dict objects

Tags: python, pandas

I have a scoring scale in a table/dataframe. I want to read the read frame and convert that to multiple dict objects.
I have table:

```
col_ref col_cutoff col_value
C1      10          100
C1      20          200
C1      Miss        500
C1      Null        100
C2      A           250
C2      B           200
C2      Null        0
C2      Miss        100
```

I want to convert this to 2 dict objects:

```
C1_Dict = {
    'Miss' : 500,
    'Null'    :100,
    'VALS'    : [
        (10, 100),
        (20, 2000)
    ]
}

C2_Dict = {
    'Miss' : 100,
    'Null'    :0,
    'VALS'    : [
        (A, 250),
        (B, 200)
    ]
}
```

Here is what  I started with.. But I can't figure further

```
import pandas as pd

def panda_2_dict(pd):
    pdf_ref = pd.read_csv()
    col_refs = pd.pdf_ref.[Col_ref.distinct]
    For each i in col_refs
             col_ref_i = {col_cutoff:col_val}
    return col_ref_i
```

I am expecting a list of dict objects(here 2).

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
  col_ref col_cutoff  col_value
0      C1         10        100
1      C1         20        200
2      C1       Miss        500
3      C1       Null        100
4      C2          A        250
5      C2          B        200
6      C2       Null          0
7      C2       Miss        100

gb = df.groupby('col_ref')

for k, v in gb:
    print k
    a = (v[:2].set_index('col_cutoff')['col_value'].to_dict()).items()
    b = v[2:].set_index('col_cutoff')['col_value'].to_dict()
    b['VALS'] = a
    print b

    C1
    {'VALS': [('10', 100), ('20', 200)], 'Null': 100, 'Miss': 500}
    C2
    {'VALS': [('A', 250), ('B', 200)], 'Null': 0, 'Miss': 100}
```